# isset returns true on a array when its parent value is a string not and array

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I encountered a strange issue with one of my arrays. The array looks like this then I do a print_r() on it:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1688
    [pCid] => 1992
    [category] => 177
    [archive] => 0
    [catid] => 
    [pid] => 
    [order_nr] => 1
    [cOrder] => 1
    [cSeo] => no-colour
    [order_id] => 0
    [price] => 8.99
    [sale_price] => 7.99
    [sale_expiry] =>
    [oPrices] => 7.99
    [member_price] => 6.99
    [set] => 0
)
```

and when I do a simmple

```
if(isset($array['set']['stock'])){}
```

it returns true when the $array['set'] currentlly equals 0.

```
var_dump(isset($array['set']['stock'])) //bool(true)
```

returns true

Any ideas why is this happening?

(I resolved the check issue by doing is_array($array['set']) check but still not sure why is the isset not working)

I noticed that you can replicate the same issue like this:

```
<?php
$colour = array();
$colour['set'] = '0';

var_dump(isset($colour['set']['stock'])); //will return true
?>
```

Comment: isset returns false for me when I run the code as above.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  I'm using 5.3.2 and isset is behaving as expected.  Also are you sure the value of the array isn't changing before you do the isset check?  Perhaps you can post a more complete example of your code.

Comment: my PHP version is "PHP Version 5.3.5"

Comment: More importantly, why are you using isset() on a non-array? While PHP allows this, it is completely unintuitive, if not plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An string is an array of characters. When the ['stock'] array is compared it compares the first character as it's looking at a string.

```
<?php
$colour = array();
$colour['set'] = 'foo';

var_dump($colour['set']['stock']); // Returns 'f'
?>
```

Returns 'f' for example.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (as in most other languages) strings can be accessed as arrays of characters.

So when you do `$str['stock']` you really are accessing the `'stock'` offset in the `$str`. As strings have only numeric offsets the string `'stock'` is cast to an integer and as it doesn't contain any numbers the result is `0`. Thus you access `$str[0]`, which is the first character of the string, which is set.

Answer (score -1):

isset() checks if a particular variable or array element exists. A variable/element that contains ANYTHING, including a `null` or a `0` is still set, because it exists. If you want to check for non-zero contents, then use `empty()` instead, which will come back true if the variable exists but contains `''`, `null`, `0`, `'0'`, etc... However, you'd still need to do an isset test, as empty() will trigger a "no such array key" warning if you attempt to run it on an array key which truly does not exist.